# Why is this printing "X" and not the value? How can I print the value?

Tags: plsql

```
    DECLARE
        a CONSTANT NUMBER := 3;
        b NUMBER NOT NULL := 5;
    BEGIN
        :X := :X + a + b + 3;
    END;
    .
    RUN
    PRINT :X
```

Comment: Do you have the value of :X initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Prints the value for me ...

```
SQL> var x number
SQL> exec :x := 10

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> DECLARE
  2     a   CONSTANT NUMBER := 3;
  3     b            NUMBER NOT NULL := 5;
  4  BEGIN
  5     :X := :X + a + b + 3;
  6  END;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :x

         X
----------
        21

SQL>
```